# How to save as web page in Selenium Webdriver Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to save a complete webpage using Ctrl+S in Selenium Webdriver JS (Firefox).
I can call out the save as dialog using this code:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName('html')).sendKeys(Key.CONTROL + 's');
```

Now the dialog is out. But I dont know how to name the file nor how to hit the enter.
Is there anyway to do this (interact with the dialog) in Selenium Webdriver JS or maybe even bypass the save as dialog and just save it onto the disk?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not interact with native dialogs. You can try a workaround for this.

Instead of saving the web page, you can save the `view-source` in a file.

Let's say you want to save `google.com` page.

- Open url with `view-source` like so.

`driver.get("view-source:http://www.google.com");`

- Select all the contents of page by simulating `Ctrl+a` and `Ctrl+c` like so.
  This is dotnet code example. You can find something similar in Js.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.KeyDown(Keys.LeftControl)
      .SendKeys("a")
      .SendKeys("c")
      .Build()
      .Perform();
```

- Format data store we stored in clipboard.

`string source = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);`

- Save to file.

`File.WriteAllText(@"PathToSaveTheSource", source);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo in Java language:

```
/* 1. get current web page source which is the complete html */
String pageHtmlSource = driver.getPageSource();
// you will get things like this:
// <html>
//   <head>
//   ...
//   </head>
//   <body>
//   ...
//   </body>
// </html>


/* 2. then save the String into a file */
```

Note that there are some differences between `driver.getPageSource()` and `Ctrl+s`. `driver.getPageSource()` only gets the html source, while `Ctrl+s` can also saves js/css.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate Solution:

The "Save As" dialog cannot be interacted with via Selenium (you need some external program). I use `require('child_process').exec()` to run a .bat file to run a .vbs script that sends keys.

You can bypass the "Save As" dialog by giving a default download directory to chromedriver: [#setDownloadPath](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Driver.html#setDownloadPath).

I have not seen a firefox alternative for this.

Sadly, this code to simulate "Ctrl" + S is not working for me:

```js
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName('html')).sendKeys(Key.CONTROL + 's');
```